# get the data of an array in a stdClass Object

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

I'm a novice programmer and I'm a bit lost rigth now. I would like to get the data from "gameId" and save it into a variable.

printing $recentgames:

```
print_r($recentgames);
```

returns me this:

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [summonerId] => 40300606,
     [games] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
          [gameId] => 2102575613 ...
```

I want to store "2102575613" into `$gamesid`. But my code does not work.

```
$gamesid = $recentgames->array[0]->gameId;

//I have also tried this code
$gamesid = $recentgames->object->games->array[0]->gameId; 

//and this one 
$gamesid = $recentgames->$object->$games->$array[0]->gameId;
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `$gamesid=$recentgames->games[0]->gameId;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

`$recentgames->games[0]->gameId`

You access objects with `$object->property` and array like `$array['key']`.